# Add shipping methods in Magento for multiple stores with single website

Tags: php, multistore, shipping-methods

I have configured Magento for multiple stores with single website.

But how do i set shipping methods for different stores.

> If the customer selects  **store1**, Need to show different shipping
>   options. (i.e **Door delivery and store pickup**)
>
> If the customer selects  **store2**, Need to show different shipping
>   options. (i.e only **store pickup**)

Is it possible to set different shipping options for different stores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the scope of your configuration in the upper left. There you can choose the store, then you can configure the different shipping methods for the different store views. If this is not possible, because the scope is website, you have two possibilites:

1. Change the scope (but be sure, that the code doesn't break) - no good idea
2. Add a second website and configure the shipping methods as intended

[image: Magento backend showing the store switcher]
[Thanks to inchoo for the image](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue recently and wanted to post the solution for anyone else who ran into it.

I discovered after setting up multiple stores that while Flat Rate and Free Shipping methods showed up on our second website, the Table Rates did not. The reason is because the table rates file was missing from the second website configuration.

Simple export the table rates .csv file from the store that works (you will need to select the actual store, rather than 'Default Configuration', under "change configuration scope"), change the configuration scope to your new store, and upload the .csv that you just exported.

Comment: Welcome on Magento SE and thanks for sharing your solution.